# JPA n+1 iteration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity which has no primary key or foreign key reference, but i need to have  uni directional entity for using the or extracting relational entity. 
Using Spring Data jpa.

below are entity classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR_PARTS")
Class  CarParts {

@id
@Column(name="PART_ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name="PART_NAME")
private String partName

}

@Entity
@Table(name="CAR_HISTORY")
Class  CarHistory {

@id
@Column(name="CAR_HIST_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="PART_NAME")
private String part;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.lazy,optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="PART_NAME",referencedColumnName="PART_NAME",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private CarPart carpart;
@column(name="SUBMIT_DATE")
private Date submitedDate;

    }
```

DAO Class:

public interface CarHistoryDAO extends JpaRepository,JpaSpecificationExecutor {
}

Service Class :

```
  public class CarhistoryServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  private CarHistoryDAo carHistoryDAO;

  public List<CarHistory> findCarHistory(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    List<CarHistory> hists = 
     carhistoryDAO.findAll(where(historyBySubmitedDate(startDate,endDate)));
   }
   public static Specification<CarHistory> historyBySubmitedDate(
            final Date startDate, final Date endDate) {
        return new Specification<CarHistory>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<CarHistory> variableRoot,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> q, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                Predicate p1 = cb.between(
                        variableRoot.<Date> get("submitedDate"),
                        DateUtils.truncate(startDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        DateUtils.ceiling(endDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                return cb.and(p1);
            }
    };
}
```

with the above relation , when ever fetch CarHistory entity i am getting n+1 iteration for Carpart entity,

I am using Spring data jpa, implemented to use specification in spring data jpa.
Is there any way i can avoid n+1 iteration issue.
I tried with onetoone instead of manytoone

Comment: which repository method are you using for retrieval? or is it custom. Add that please

Comment: updated the dao and service

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `n+1` issue you have to fetch `CarPart` instances along with the `CarHistory` entities. There are multiple solutions:

1. Map `CarHistory.carPart` as `EAGER` (not a good solution)
2. Write custom query and fetch `CarHistory.carPart` eagerly, e.g. `from CarHistory ch JOIN FETCH ch.carPart where ...`

Here is the article explaining how [to initialize lazy associations and when to use them](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/)